# Partially Valid PKI certificate--But still we are able to login to our Application

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure

User having a PKI card with an invalid  PKI certificate (Among the two PKI certificates – One certificate is revoked (Damaged/ officially Cancelled) and another certificate is active)and try to login in Our Application after that user is allowed to login into our application successfully.

- Once after revoked the PKI certificate , It will take maximum 12 hours to reflect in application usage.
- This delay is due to updating  the changes related to certificates in many servers across world.

After the 20+ hours partially valid certificate PKI card is not allowed to login 
into windows but Using same partially valid PKI card, our application security login is successful.

Please help with this conflict....

Comment: It looks like this is a problem with your passcard infrastructure, and possibly with the vendor supplying it. I'm not sure how we could possibly help you given the very little information you provide.